# Push Json Data as individual Objects not as one long Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to push the data from an API into an Array of objects..

I want

```
myFXdata {[ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src]},
         {[ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src]},
         {[ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src]},
         {[ccypair], [resistance], ...etc},
```

But I get

```
myFXdata {[ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src],
         [ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src],
         [ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src],
         [ccypair], [resistance], ...etc}
```

My code is

```
 var myFXdata = [];
 
 for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
    
    myFXData.push((collection[i].ccyPair),   (collection[i].resistance), (collection[i].support), (collection[i].trend.src));  
         }

    console.log(dailyfxTech)
```

I think I need to push into a new object each time, but

```
     myFXData.push({collection[i].ccyPair});
```

gives the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['. Expected a ':' following the property name 'collection'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: pls can you provide demo in jsfiddle with your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you say you want is just not possible, since it is not a valid js object:

```
{[ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src]}
```

What that snippet tells me is that you want to end up with an array of objects, where each object contains 4 properties, that have no keys, and that are arrays by themselves. That just doesn't make much sense, and keys are required for objects in js

Your snippet should probably look something like

```
{'pair': ccypair, 'resistance': resistance, 'support': support, 'src': trend.src}
```

If an array is fine for your case you could also do:

```
[ccypair, resistance, support, trend.src]
```

depending on the format you choose, it should be easy enough to push them onto your array

```
myFXData.push({
    pair: collection[i].ccyPair, 
    collection: collection[i].resistance, 
    support: collection[i].support, 
    src: collection[i].trend.src
});
```

or

```
myFXData.push([
    collection[i].ccyPair, 
    collection[i].resistance, 
    collection[i].support, 
    collection[i].trend.src
]);
```

So in the first case you will end up with an array of objects, while in the second case you'll get an array of arrays, or a two dimensional array as that would be called.

I hope this all make sense. Feel free to ask if not.

Comment: That is fantastic, thank you. I was getting myself in knots over objects and arrays but your first case does exactly what I want. Thanks again.